# how to use drawline function only once during form load?

Tags: c#

I am using drawline function for drawing horizontal and vertical lines for making X-Y coordinate graph.The problem in it is blinking of backgroundgraph everytime i draw some other shape such as rectangle and ellipse. everytime i write a new shape object drawline function executes and reloads so the blinking effect till i stop drawing.How to resolve this problem?I am using drawline function only for this backgroundgraph and  not using any line shape in my application.I have tried drawline in formload but it doesn't work as the parameters for formload and drawline mismatches.So how can i make this graph constant(calling only once)?

here is code:

```
    private void draw(Graphics e, Point mold, Point mcur, int mshape, float mwidth, Color mcolor)
    {

        int numOfCells = 100;
        int cellSize = 25;

            for (int i = 0; i < numOfCells; i++)
            {
                Pen pn = new Pen(Color.LightSlateGray, ((mwidth - 1) / 25));
                // Vertical
                e.DrawLine(pn, i * cellSize, 0, i * cellSize, numOfCells * cellSize);
                // Horizontal
                e.DrawLine(pn, 0, i * cellSize, numOfCells * cellSize, i * cellSize);
            }

        Pen p = new Pen(mcolor, mwidth);
        switch (mshape)
        {
            case 0: e.DrawRectangle(p, rec(mold, mcur));
                      break;
            case 1: e.DrawEllipse(p, rec(mold, mcur));
                      break;
        }
    }        
    private Rectangle rec(Point P1, Point P2)
    {
        Rectangle a = new Rectangle(); 
        a.X = (P1.X > P2.X ? P2.X : P1.X);
        a.Y = (P1.Y > P2.Y ? P2.Y : P1.Y);
        a.Width = Math.Abs(P1.X - P2.X);
        a.Height = Math.Abs(P1.Y - P2.Y);
        return a;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use off-screen buffering or Double Buffering.

1. Create a Memory Object
2. Perform the drawing in the memory graphics object
3. Once everything is done in the memory, transfer the whole content to your screen

Read the below code project article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12870/Don-t-Flicker-Double-Buffer